# Git workflow for training workshop

Tags: git

I'm leading a training workshop where participants will be asked to follow along with me as I talk about new concepts. Each concept will build on the previous one. The structure of the workshop will be:

- Introduce Concept01
- Lab for Concept01
- Introduce Concept02
- Lab for Concept02, including Concept01
- etc...

Most of the people in the room will not be technical people, but they are still interested in the concepts and I'd like to make it easy for them to keep up. The "coding" part of the labs will be interesting to the technical people, but running the result should be available to even those who can't keep up with the "coding" parts.

I want to insert "reset" or "check" points where if they are struggling with a portion they can catch up their working directory so they can move on.

Easiest way for me to manage this is to use git and have scripts they can run. I figured I could put the solutions in branches (concept01, concept02, etc) and then use a script to reset their working directory. But I'm not sure how to structure the script. Do I...

1. have it do a `git reset --hard` in the directory and then checkout the next branch?
2. have it do a `git add -A`, followed by `git commit` in the directory, and then checkout the new branch?
3. Do something else entirely?

I'm leaning towards using method (2) right now. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

On the 1st method, they will lose everything they have done, and move to the solution branch.

On the 2nd one, they will save their work on the current branch and then move to the solution branch.

Choose 2nd method if you think it's interesting for them to keep their work, continue the training without being stuck and then they would go back later on their work tofinish it.

Answer (score 0):

How about `git checkout .` to reset to the latest commit?